# Presenting a view for the first time in appDelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

**The goal:**

When my app starts up - I need it to display a view before it gets to the "Home" screen. Its a tab bar application and this view is not part of the tabbar.

I am using Storyboards and Xcode 5 - iOS7 only app.

**The problem:**

I have code that will check if the app is first launch or not. Based on that, I then want to present a one time only view to the user.

**What I have tried:**

The following code is in the appDelegate of the application as this is where it all starts. I call the following bit of code in there:

```
-(void)showCountrySettings
{

    if (self.termsHaveBeenAccepted){

        BBCounterySettingsViewController *countrySettings = [[BBCounterySettingsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"View" bundle:nil];

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

I get compile errors as `[self.navigationController..]` doesn't exist. Nor does `[self.tabbarcontroller...];`

This is obvious as I don't have properties setup for these - but how do I go about resolving this and connecting the tab bar to the storyboard?

What am I missing?

Comment: do u have NavigationController or TabBarColler in ur StoryBoard as staring point.

Comment: TabBarController - which is set as the initial view.

Comment: are u just want to show some view as pop or else u need to show a viewController.

Comment: Its just a viewController that displays T&Cs - it needs to show only once. Modal view could work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    if(!isAgreementAccepted)
    {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDD"];
    self.window.rootViewController=vc;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

If agreement is not accepted set the T&C `viewController` as `rootViewController` when user click the accept button then set the `TabBarviewController` as root.

u can access the widow object through application delegate any where

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window].rootViewController=tabViewController.
```

Comment: This seems to be the easiest way to do it. I have tested and it does exactly as I need it to. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change the rootviewcontroller of window programaticaly

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

   UIStoryboard *aStoryBoard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
   UITabBarController *aTabCtrl=[aStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tab"];
   FirstVC *aFirstCtrl=[aStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"First"];

   if(self.termsHaveBeenAccepted)
      self.window.rootViewController=aFirstCtrl;
   else
      self.window.rootViewController=aTabCtrl;
   return YES;
}
```

This will definitely work I have tested.

Comment: Thanks - yes it does work - I will keep this code in mind. I need to present another screen and this code will help there.

Comment: Yes you can change any screen.

Answer (score 0):

If Tabbarcontroller is your root viewcontroller, then using below code will resolve the issue in your appdelegate.

```
 -(void)showCountrySettings
  {

     if (self.termsHaveBeenAccepted){

    BBCounterySettingsViewController *countrySettings = [[BBCounterySettingsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"View" bundle:nil];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER"];
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    [tabBarController presentModalviewcontroller:vc animated:YES completionblock:nil];
  }
```

Comment: Thank you - however [self.tabbarcontroller... ]; gives an error: "Propert tabbarcontroller not found on object of type BBAppDelegate"

Comment: UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController; By the way, Why Down vote? Give proper reason for down vote so that everyone can learn.

Comment: Thanks - however I get the following message: 2014-01-06 12:12:45.327 BidOrBuy[1168:70b] Warning: Attempt to present <BBCounterySettingsViewController: 0x99492b0> on <UITabBarController: 0x8d6ca70> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: It seems your rootviewcontroller is not formed fully. Call the method with some delay. [self performSelector:@selector(showCountrySettings) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];.

Answer (score 0):

add your viewcontroller superview of tabbarcontroller as first time else call tabbarcontroller alone