# call method of different view controller in app delegate while a pushing new controller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller, appdelegate

I am working on a chat application and on successful login I want to push view a controller and show tab bar to user.

following is the code I have used for it

This is my **TabBarViewCtr**

```
  appdel=(TabBarAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

    nextFirstViewCtr = [[FirstViewCtr alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewCtr" bundle:nil];
    nextSecondViewCtr=[[SecondViewCtr alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewCtr" bundle:nil];
    nextThirdViewCtr=[[ThirdViewCtr alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewCtr" bundle:nil];
    nextForthViewCtr=[[ForthViewCtr alloc] initWithNibName:@"ForthViewCtr" bundle:nil];
    nextsixviewctr=[[sixviewctr alloc] initWithNibName:@"sixviewctr" bundle:nil];
}
else
{
    nextFirstViewCtr = [[FirstViewCtr alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewCtr-iPad" bundle:nil];
    nextSecondViewCtr=[[SecondViewCtr alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewCtr-iPad" bundle:nil];
    nextThirdViewCtr=[[ThirdViewCtr alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewCtr-iPad" bundle:nil];
    nextForthViewCtr=[[ForthViewCtr alloc] initWithNibName:@"ForthViewCtr-iPad" bundle:nil];
    nextsixviewctr=[[sixviewctr alloc] initWithNibName:@"sixviewctr-iPad" bundle:nil];
}
[nextFirstViewCtr setTitle:@"1st tab"];
[nextSecondViewCtr setTitle:@"2nd tab"];
[nextThirdViewCtr setTitle:@"3rd tab"];
[nextForthViewCtr setTitle:@"4th tab"];
[nextsixviewctr setTitle:@"5th tab"];


nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nextFirstViewCtr];
nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nextSecondViewCtr];
nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nextThirdViewCtr];
nav4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nextForthViewCtr];
nav5 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nextsixviewctr];
nav1.navigationBarHidden=YES;
nav2.navigationBarHidden=YES;
nav3.navigationBarHidden=YES;
nav4.navigationBarHidden=YES;
nav5.navigationBarHidden=YES;

MainTabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
MainTabBar.delegate = self;
[MainTabBar setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1,nav2,nav3,nav4,nav5,nil]];
MainTabBar.view.frame=self.view.frame;
MainTabBar.selectedIndex=0;
[self.view addSubview:MainTabBar.view];
```

In the login view controller i have called connect method which is in app del and this works fine, on call of the connect method and for correct credential the method which is in app del for authentication get called.

The authentication method is as follows it is in **TabBarAppDelegate**.

```
    - (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender
    {
   DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

   [self goOnline];

       LoginPassViewController *obj_login = [[LoginPassViewController alloc] init];
       [obj_login nextOne];
 }
```

The nexone method looks like following which is in the loginpassviewcnt. It also get called but view is not pushed.

this method is in **LoginPassViewController** and get called from **TabBarAppDelegate**

```
  -(void)nextOne{

   TabBarViewCtr *MainTab;

   if(MainTab==nil){
    MainTab=[[TabBarViewCtr alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabBarViewCtr" bundle:nil];
   }
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:MainTab animated:YES];
  }
```

When the **nextOne** method is called form **LoginPassViewController** it does works as required, but not when it called from **TabBarAppDelegate** .
I am not getting any error or even application is also not crashing can anyone please let me know how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the LoginPassViewController a subclass of UINavigationController?

Comment: your content seems to be not clear, post the exact code with Class-Name

Comment: @yoninja thanks for comment -- its just a simple view controller. when i call the nextOne method from the LoginPassViewController controller it does shows the tab bar view but its not working when the method is called from the appdel.

Comment: @CoolMonster Thanks for your reply, I have edited the question, hope its more clear now.

Comment: LoginPassViewController *obj_login = [[LoginPassViewController alloc] init];
       [obj_login nextOne]; 
why u created the loginpassviewcontroller once again

Comment: @CoolMonster without it how i will be able to call the method of the LoginPassViewController, is there anyway to do it. I found this way to call LoginPassViewController method from appdel from google and it does call method also.

Comment: but its not the actual viewController present inside navigation controller. When u create a new ViewContreller, navigationcontroller property will be nil. u cant use this to push a viewController

Comment: @CoolMonster thanks for your time, so what is the way to do this.

Comment: if u never whant ur login controller again measn u simply set ur tabBarviewController instance as root view of application window. or else u can get the navigationController form the rootviewController instance itself.http://stackoverflow.com/a/20947860/1405008