# How to display navigation controller (set of view controllers) such as login or register before adding UITabBarController

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

I had an application in which I need to have a login or register system before the tab bar controller is added to the window, such as in Instagram.

I have added 5 navigation controllers (with view controller as its root) to the `UITabBarController` and then set it as the root of the window. Before that, I need to have another `UINavigationController` for the login system.

If I add that, how do I remove it before adding tab?

Another problem is that I also have to handle logging out, so I need to come back to it.

Can anybody help me with me how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20947860/1405008
try this method

Comment: setup TabbarControll after Log in i mean login Button Click Event. when you sucessfull logged in then setup tabbar controller with its Navigation Controller

Comment: @NitinGohel not getting u?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to you loading Loginview From Delegate window as we did Normally. and from Logged Success its button click you set `TabbarController` like this:-

```
                UIViewController *viewControllerPostalCode2 = [[cntrServices alloc] initWithNibName:@"cntrServices" bundle:nil];
                UIViewController *viewControllerPostalCode3 = [[cntrInquiryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"cntrInquiryViewController" bundle:nil];


                UINavigationController *navPostage1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewControllerPostalCode2];
                UINavigationController *navPostage2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewControllerPostalCode3];

                //        
                navPostage1.navigationBar.tintColor =DARK_BACKGROUNDNavigation;
                navPostage2.navigationBar.tintColor =DARK_BACKGROUNDNavigation;
                //        
                self.tabBarForServicesController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
                self.tabBarForServicesController.delegate=self;
                self.tabBarForServicesController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navPostage1,navPostage2,nil];

                [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.tabBarForServicesController animated:YES];
```

I Done this type of Task using this method and at the Logged Out just poptoRootviewController work back to the Logged in Screen.

Comment: Nitin Gohel's approach and answer is correct But in this case I just hope that you don't have to deal with different interface orientations for different view controllers inside your TabBar's Navigation Controllers.

Comment: OP about to navigation from log in to tab-bar and deal with different interface orientation is different think that not suitable with OP  might be this app in only portrait so i just try to attempt this question for way of navigation log in to tab. and for different interface orientations user can need to create tabbarController navigation Category overwrite according to navigation orientation.

Comment: Nitin, Agreed. I just mentioned about one aspect. I said your answer and approach is correct and I up-voted for that as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this like adding my tabbarcontroller as rootViewController to UIWindow and in applicationbecomeactive  delegate i present a controller with navigation controller like when required and simply dismiss the controller when authentication done

```
UIViewController *topViewController = [self.navController topViewController];
if (![topViewController isKindOfClass:[LGLoginViewController class]]) {
    [self.navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.navController = nil;

    LGLoginViewController* loginView = [[LGLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LGLoginViewController"bundle:nil];

    if (!self.navController) {
        self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginView];
    } else {
        [self.navController initWithRootViewController:loginView];
    }

    self.navController.delegate = self;
    [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:self.navController animated:NO];
}
```