# iOS complex navigation between view controllers

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a complex flow between view controllers (vc). When my main view controller shows, it checks if a user is logged in, and if not, it pushes a log in vc in `viewWillAppear`. The login then can the push a register vc. Further, on app's very first start, it also shows a special vc, also from the main vc's `viewWillAppear` (just once). It does not matter if the user has logged in or skipped the log in.

The app can be opened also by custom URLs, which should open one of my vcs. The app must start/resume at that screen without any visble transition between vcs. All this flow is handled from my main vc, which handles this in `viewWillAppear` and in `didBecomeActive` which is an observer for app's `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`. Some of those custom URLs must open the login screen first.

My naive approach was to handle all this logic in my main vc's `viewWillAppear` where I pushed vcs base on the current state. This works for pushing the login screen on app's start without any problem. The problem is that when I return from the login and I need to push another vc. The main navigation controller knows that something was pushed (the back button becomes visible) but the old vc is visible (the main), with partially broken views, and does not react to touch events. Tapping the back button makes a complete mess from my app.

I googled and the problem seems to be that we cannot push a vc while another one is popping. I have found a [BufferedNavigationController](https://github.com/Plasma/BufferedNavigationController), which solves this, but it does not work correctly under iOS7 yet. I do not even see any logs in device's console.

Another issues is that while the app is in the background a memory warning could mess my vc's and the app has completely different startup than a normal resume from the background.

At the moment I came with a quick hack where I create a custom backstack for all the situations and set it as the navigation controller's back stack and push the last vc on top of that stack. Then in the login/register screens I modify the backstack if a user skipped the login/register process. This is an ugly hack an not a very future proof solution. I would like to centrally controll the pushing of vcs in one place and there cannot be any visible transition between them in that situation.

Is there any better/more robust solution to achieve this? I cannot have visible transition when returning back from one vc (this is animated) and the vc beneath it should push another on top of it while it becomes visible (no animation of this push). So it looks like we return to a completely different screen? No matter if it can be confusing for users, that is for another question.

**EDIT 1:** I am targeting iOS7 and newer only.

**EDIT 2:** Here is a [sample demo](https://github.com/martinflorek/ios-complex-navigation-problem-demo/blob/master/ComplexNavigation/ViewControllers/MainViewController.m) which shows my issue. I directed the link to he main vc, which pushes other vcs in its `viewWillAppear` (the other vcs are not important). It is just for presentaion purposes.

This demo shows logs into console "nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar" and "Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted." which do not show up in my big project. I know what they mean, but how can I push a vc when antoher is popping away? The mentioned BufferedNavigationController does not work for me on iOS 7 (and it is not a problem, that it does not use ARC).

**EDIT 3**: When I start the provided demo for the first time, it will open the login screen instead of the main - good. Then after tapping the login it goes back to the main screen and should instantly push the another screen without the main being visible. It does not do that, the main is visible but the navbar thinks there is something above the main, thus the visible back button. It corrupts the backstack...

Comment: I cant able to figure out the issue but https://github.com/vasanth3008/NavigaitonDemo.git this method may help u

Comment: When you start the demo for the first time, it will open the login screen instead of the main - good. Then after tapping the login it goes back to the main screen and should instantly push the another screen without the main being visible. It does not do that, the main is visible but the navbar thinks there is something above the main, thus the visible back button. It corrupts the backstack. Your solution disables pushing the another screen, which is not what I need...

Comment: is there any problem with that

Comment: Yes. I need to push that another screen after returning from log in. That is the whole point of my question. And it is not just about the another screen, I have more than one screen that I need to quickly push when returning to the main screen.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20947860/1405008

Refer this for your first scenario like open login or other view controller.

For custom URL u can also use the same logic and check and present when its arrive from custom URL.

Always set the root view Controller will the easiest way to do this kind of different navigation stuffs in Your application also this approach avoid unwanted view-controller in stack.

Comment: `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is not called when the app resumes from the background. It is called only when the app was killed/not yet started. My root view controller is always a navigation vc, which is set in a storyboard. Then in my app I use segues or push vcs manually. And it still does not solve pushing a vc when antoher one is popping.

Comment: Why u want to pop while pushing

Comment: I want the opposite, push while popping. My main vc needs to push another vc when it returns from a specific vc, without transition, before the mian vc becomes visible, that is why I use `viewWillAppear` So it looks like the top vc returned to a different screen.

Comment: - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application,Use this method to change the viewController hierachy

Comment: Is that method called when I push and pop view controllers whithin my app? Isn't it called only whe the whole app will enter foreground?

Comment: Whetehr u want to see the animation for trasition or not

Comment: I just tried it and it is not called on app's start/restart, only when the app resumes from the background. It is also not called when I navigate within the app.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46320/discussion-between-coolmonster-and-shelll)